# TypeScript: Return type of combined generic type is always unknown

Tags: typescript, generics, design-patterns

I want to create a settings store. The user can add a setting with a value of any type. Then he can retrieve a value and get it correctly typed.

My thinking was: this sounds like connected generic type arguments. The type of the result is dependent on the type of the argument to the `getSetting()` method. So I tried creating said `getSetting()` method such that it takes a type as input, and based on that type it should be able to infer the return type. This approach uses the type as a key to get the correct information.

Below is my current approach. It seems to be somewhat close to what I want, but the return type of `getSetting` is always `unknown`. In the example I would expect it to be `number`, though.

```
abstract class Setting<T> {
  abstract value: T;
}
class SD extends Setting<number> {
  value = 0;
}

let getSetting = <T extends Setting<K>, K>(type: new () => T): K => {
  // return value somehow
};

let setting = getSetting(SD); // type of setting is unkown instead of number
```

Where is my error? Or is there a completely different way to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type inference happens from arguments not from other type parameters, so you need to move `K` in the parameter list in some way.

The simplest version would be to drop `T`, you can just  say the constructor return `Setting<K>`, any derived class will work as well, and since you don't use `T` in any other capacity, this seems like the simplest solution:

```
let getSetting = <K,>(type: new () => Setting<K>): K => {
  return new type().value
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=13&pln=6&pc=2#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgygUwhAlgHYDmAPACoB8CA3gFAIKiQzwIBuwyArtgFwJyAbjoBfOijQZMAEQTYAHhGyEAJtNwESpQtwC2IbFGr1GnHtgQBeBAAYR4uslwJiuHHiLFrCUgGkAGkoACggATwAHfgRCbAB3BGCASmtqDy0yP0okgT9U2gYEKFxuKEIY+IRwqOSAOnNeMREnFzBNLx83CHSvYNkkoQQgA)

If you do need `T` for something else not in this example there are several other options. You could use both `T` and `Setting<K>` in the constructor return type:

```
let getSetting = <T extends Setting<K>, K>(type: new () => T & Setting<K>): K => {
  return new type().value
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgygUwhAlgHYDmAPACoB8CA3gFAIKiQzwIBuwyArtgFwJyAbjoBfOijQZMAEQTYAHhGyEAJtNwESpQtwC2IbFGr1GnHtgQBeBAAYR4uslwJiuHHiLFrCCvKUq6liaXqQA0pQANAgRABQQAJ4ADvwIhNgA7gixAJTW1OQIAGTBntoROQJh+bQMCFC43FCEaZkIiSm5AHTmvGIiTi5gISQ+bhAeWsSxsjlCCEA)

Or you could do away with `K` altogether and extract the type of value using an index type query:

```
let getSetting = <T extends Setting<any>>(type: new () => T): T['value'] => {
  return new type().value
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgygUwhAlgHYDmAPACoB8CA3gFAIKiQzwIBuwyArtgFwJyAbjoBfOijQZMAEQTYAHhGyEAJtNwESpQtwC2IbFGr1GnHtgQBeBAAYR4uslwJiuHHiLFrCCvKUq6liaXqTAhACelJQAFBARAA78CITYAO4IMQCU1tTkWQLkANoA5Oa8JQC6ubQMCFC43FCEKekI8UnZAHTl2GIiTi5gISQ+bhAeWsQxsllCCEA)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the great answer! Option 2 and 3 do exactly what I want. Just a question regarding option 2: what does `new () => T & Setting<K>` mean? What does the ampersand do here?

Comment: @SebastianGebert It's an intersection type, If you have a type defined as `A & B`  any value must satisfy  both `A` and `B` to be of type `A & B`. In the case of inference, this will lead to whatever value is being matched to be the inference source for both types in the intersection. In this case the return type of the constructor will be matched against both `T` and `Settings<K>` leading to inferences for both `T` and `K` independently